# HTML dropdown elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make an HTML page that contains a dropdown element that can also go whithin another dropdown, like at this page: https://coda.io/d/_dIXWo7SiwOb/Untitled_su1WJ

I do **not** want a dropdown list.

I tried a few things, but they either couldn't stack, or they were just dropdown lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of examples/tutorials out there on how to do something like this with Bootstrap and jquery.  I hacked out a quick example that seems to do what you want using an example from W3 schools and it seems to be working reasonably well.  Credit to W3 schools for providing the base example I worked from to come up with the end result you wanted. I will leave it to you to look at the code and modifying formatting (e.g. where carets go) and such, but the basic logic and functionality seem to be what you are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">
  <h2>Untitled</h2>
                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Level 1
    <span class="caret"></span></span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sublevel 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Sublevel 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sublevel 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Sublevel 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```